# WDS server не грузится на 64 архитектуре

Tags: windows, администрирование

Доброго времени суток. Помогите разобраться. Установлен Windows server 2008 R2. На нем стоит WDS + Pxelinux. Проблема в том что компы на 86 архитектуре нормально прогружают wds. Но на x64 не хочет грузить. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Где покопаться. DHCP стоит на FreeBSD, находится в той же подсети что и WDS.

Comment: А что пишет, когда на 64 не грузится?

Comment: pxe-e51: No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/455202/315697 вроде та же самая проблема.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: К сожалению не то.